# Python icmp socket server (not tcp\udp)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to write a socket server in Python that can receive ICMP packets.

Here's my code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s.bind((host,0))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

However, I dont know how to receive the packets - I tried using s.listen but it failed.
What am I missing or am I completly in the wrong direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before in twisted and I set the socket up like this:

```
import socket

def listen():
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
  while 1:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1508)
    print "Packet from %r: %r" % (addr,data)
```

Comment: What is 1508 in the s.recvfrom method call?

Comment: The result of a quick search for the maximum ICMP packet size. This parameter has to be specified (maximum amount of data to be received at once). Yes, depending on the network and the network stack you could receive larger packets which would be truncated by this. If you find that data is missing, try increasing this value.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the accepted answer, this code unpacks the received ICMP header and displays its data (ICMP type, code, etc)

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    while 1:
        recPacket, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        icmp_header = recPacket[20:28]
        type, code, checksum, p_id, sequence = struct.unpack('bbHHh', icmp_header)
        print "type: [" + str(type) + "] code: [" + str(code) + "] checksum: [" + str(checksum) + "] p_id: [" + str(p_id) + "] sequence: [" + str(sequence) + "]"
```