# How to receive multicast join reports (IGMP v3)

Tags: typescript, networking, multicast, igmp

I want to see which Multicast-Join-Reports fly through the network in which my host computer resides in. For that I've written a little TypeScript program, that joins the multicast group '224.0.0.22', which is defined in [RFC3376](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3376) under 4.2.14 as the IP Destination for Multicast-Join-Reports. But I receive no requests even when I should, because I'am watching traffic via Wireshark and there Multicast-Join-Reports are send and received.

**Edit 1**: Attached is the receiving part:

```
const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();

const IGMP_V3_REPORT_MULTICAST_ADDRESS = '224.0.0.22';
const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

const ipv4Interface = interfaces['eth0'].find((i) => i.family === 'IPv4');

if (ipv4Interface) {
    socket.on('error', (e: Error) => {
        console.log(`${ifaceName}: socket error: ${e}`);
        sockResults[index] = false;
    });

    socket.on('listening', () => {
        const address = socket.address();
        console.log(`${ifaceName}: listening on ${address.address}:${address.port}`);

        console.log(`${ifaceName}: joining multicast group with address: ${IGMP_V3_REPORT_MULTICAST_ADDRESS} for local address: ${ipv4Interface.address}`);
        socket.addMembership(IGMP_V3_REPORT_MULTICAST_ADDRESS, ipv4Interface.address);
    })

    socket.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
        console.log(`${ifaceName}: got ${msg}`);
    });

    socket.bind(0);

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`${ifaceName}: dropping multicast membership for ${IGMP_V3_REPORT_MULTICAST_ADDRESS}`);
        socket.dropMembership(IGMP_V3_REPORT_MULTICAST_ADDRESS,  ipv4Interface.address);

        console.log(`${ifaceName}: closing socket`);
        socket.close();

        resolve();
    }, 120 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: you mean, the computer gets the packets but your code doesn't get them? please attach your code...

Comment: Exactly. Wireshark is showing Multicast-Join-Reports for the UPnP multicast group '239.255.255.250' and the code I attached does not receive these.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore IGMP, multicast-join, switches, and all that stuff for a moment, as you're already physically receiving the desired packets.

If you want to receive packets that are destined to `239.255.255.250`, you're gonna have to use that address (and for UPnP the relevant port) in `socket.bind()`.

These are all Python implementations, but hopefully converting to TypeScript won't be difficult: https://github.com/leslie-wang/py-multicast-example/blob/master/mcast.py and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794373/4935162).

Specifically, you need to:

`socket.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))`

which in your case should be `('239.255.255.250', 1900)`, which are the default for UPnP.

Whereas, you are binding to "any available port" with `socket.bind(0)`.

And I [believe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-socket-addmembership-method/) the parameters given to `socket.addMembership()`, should be the mcast group you want to receive messages from. The kernel, specifically the code that handles IP, needs to know to "forward" these packets upwards towards UDP.

---

By the way... there's also the option of [sniffing](https://github.com/cyphunk/snifferjs) instead of listening, in your use-case, but it may require higher privileges.

Comment: That is exactly what I do not want to do. I do not want to receive packets of a specific multicast group. I want all membership reports that fly around in a specific network. Thanks for the sniffer link, I will have a look if I can recreate the Wireshark functionality. Edit: For the snifferjs I need libpcap-dev, I can't require a dependency, that's why im trying to follow the RFC specification. Edit2: Yes, `socket.bind(0)` means bind to a random available port.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding. IGMP is over IP, it doesn't use ports. sniffing might be the way to go, in this case, maybe like [ICMP listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039225/4935162), or literally sniffing like wireshark/tcpdump. anyway, have a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket-sniffer) library

Comment: Thank you, the raw-socket-sniffer, could be exactly what I'am looking for.